# How to splice multiple array elements and insert accordingly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

```html
const data = response.data
console.log(data)
const temp = data.ssps_with_scated.splice(5, 1)(1, 3)[0]
data.ps_with_ed.splice(2, 1, 0, temp)
```

i am trying to achieve finally i got it. But issue is, i cant expect the array value same all the time. So i have decided to re-arrange the array values based on the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

```
splice(7,1)(21,3)
```

This code will cause an error. Since Array.prototpy.slice returns a new array.
It would be the same if you would do this:

```
const a = [1,2,3]
const b = a.splice(1,1);
b(2,1) // b.splice(...) is not a function
```

EDITED:
Maybe there is a faster/better solution but...
You can make it more general but for your case only:

```
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21];
const first = array[7];
const second = array[21];

// Add elements on certain indices in array (second and third)
array.splice(2, 0, first, second)

// Remove first from the array (index is 7 + 2 because we added 2 elements)
array.splice(9, 1)

// Remove 21 from the array (index is 22 - 1 because we added 2 elements and removed 1, not: number 21 is on index 22)
array.splice(21, 1);
```

Comment: Please can you just post in your original question your exact scenario. Put example array, lets say, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25] and your expected result?

Comment: Please, as i said, your code is not important here. What are you trying to achieve, i do not understand from your explanation nor your code? Give just an example array and what is the result that you wanna expect?

Answer (score 0):

`data` shouldn't be a `const` since the value is getting updated. `Splice` can also only be called on one array at a time. If you need to call it on multiple arrays, create a loop or iterate over them.

If you want to inject the current value of the 7th position into the 2nd position... you'd need to do something like...

`array.splice(2, 0, array[7])`

Comment: Yes u are right. But I need to call multiple array values. So in order to do that. Can splice array and make them

Comment: If you want to inject values at more than one index in an array, you will need to call splice more than once. You can inject multiple values at a single index like so `Array.splice(a, 0, b, c)` where a is equal to the index you want to inject values b & c.